# How to calculate time difference between two longitudes and latitudes distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, geo

Basically what I wanted to know is, how long will it take to travel from location **A** to **B**? I've the location **A** longitudes and latitudes, and **B** latitudes and longitudes.

I did lot of searching on Google but couldn't find a proper answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: first you need to calculate the distance between the two point , then estimate the velocity
and with a simple physics equation 
time = velocity x distance

Comment: Travelling how? (Walking, Driving, Flying,...). What speed?

Comment: Hi thanks for ur reply, i need the driving speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the distance between 2 sets of coordinates in a line using formulate. You can find the codes for several programming languages in https://www.geodatasource.com/developers. From the distance, you can estimate the travel time using average speed.

If you want to have accurate travel time, you need more real time information such as traffic conditions, current travel speed and route distance.